# Loki: Can move cursor on the screen but can't click on anything

Tags: release-loki, boot, usb, click

In trying to find a suitable OS to install on my 2009 Macbook, I went with Ubuntu with which I couldn't connect to Wi-Fi, so I'd like to try Elementary.

I created a bootable USB with Loki, booted on the OS without installing it and can't click on anything.

I can move the cursor around on the screen but I can't click on any icons or the applications menu..

Kind of scared to install it. Has anyone had this problem? Did it persist upon actually installing it?

Comment: I'm having the same issues with a logitech usb mouse on a desktop pc. Happens when I click outside of my currently active window. Mouse still moves, but it won't interact with the gui any more Edit: this happened in live session and also happens on full install

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is a problem with the compatibility of the trackpad.

Have you tried plugging in a mouse, and see if that works? Also, actually installing the system (as opposed to running it from a USB pen) will increase your chance at a fully working system since a bunch of software is installed from the web too (on top of the core stuff on the pen).

Lastly, you'll be able to update the system to bleeding edge, as Elementary keep releasing bug fixes at a OS level (this includes [a track pad fix](http://blog.elementary.io/post/150787296131/loki-release-follow-up)).